# Maximal cardinality of Sidon set

Tags: combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

I was trying to solve the following problem from Tao-Vu.

> Let $A$ be any additive set. Show that a Sidon set contained in $A$
> can have cardinality at most $\sqrt{2\sigma[A]|A|}.$

Suppose that $S$ is a Sidon set in $A$. Then the following set-theoretical equality is valid and the union is disjoint $$S\times S=\bigsqcup_{t\in S+S} \{(x,y)\in S\times S: x+y=t\}.$$

Since $S$ is a Sidon set, then if $\{a,b\}\neq \{c,d\} \Rightarrow a+b\neq c+d.$ Hence for any $t\in S+S$ the set $\{(x,y)\in S\times S: x+y=t\}$ has exactly two elements. Therefore $|S|^2=\sum \limits_{t\in S+S}\#\{(x,y)\in S\times S: x+y=t\}=\sum \limits_{t\in S+S}2=2|S+S|.$ Since $S+S\subset A+A,$ then $|S|^2\leq 2|A+A|$ and if we take square root we obtain desired inequality because $\sigma[A]:=\dfrac{|A+A|}{|A|}.$

Firstly I thought that this equality $|S|^2=2|S+S|$ is valid, if $S$ is a Sidon set but later I realized that it is false. If $S$ is a Sidon set then $\sigma[S]:=\dfrac{|S+S|}{|S|}$ is maximal and equal to $\dfrac{|S|+1}{2}$. But our equality implies that $\sigma[S]=\dfrac{|S|}{2}$ and this is contradiction. So something is wrong.

What is my mistake? I could not find my mistakeю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

> For any $t\in S+S$, the set $\{(x,y)\in S\times S:x+y=t\}$ has exactly two elements.

But this is not correct; if $t=a+a$ for some $a\in S$ then the corresponding set has only one element. Your idea is however correct; the correct computation is that
\begin{align}
|S|^2&=\sum_{t\in S+S}\#\{(x,y)\in S\times S:x+y=t\} \\
&=|S|+2\cdot(|S+S|-|S|) \\
&=2|S+S|-|S|.
\end{align}
We thus still get the inequality $|S^2|\leqslant 2|S+S|\leqslant 2|A+A|$, so your proof still carries through.

Comment: Oh yeah! I completely forgot the case when $t=a+a$ for some $a\in S$. My question was silly. Thank you so much for pointing out my flaw in my reasoning.

Comment: @ZFR my pleasure, happy it helped! :)